Can a family member kick out a non paying renter
Living with my cousin for 8 months. He never asked for rent but I would give money when I could. Help with household chores and buy groceries monthly. Now all of a sudden he wants me out. What legal rights do I have?

Related, from the other side: What Iowa law states that a leased tenant cannot kick out a non-leased occupant/squatter?

I doubt the law makes any distinction regarding whether you're a family member. That seems more appropriate for [interpersonal.se].

It's not clear to me whether you would be considered a "tenant" under Iowa law.  You never had a formal written agreement but you did pay some money in rent and household expenses.  Your agreement did not have a set end date either.
However, even if you were a rent-paying tenant in the legal sense, your cousin (who is effectively your landlord) could terminate your rental agreement with 30 days' notice.  See Iowa Code §§562A.9(5):

Unless the rental agreement fixes a definite term, the tenancy shall be week-to-week in case of a roomer who pays weekly rent, and in all other cases month-to-month.

and Iowa Code §§562A.34

The landlord or the tenant may terminate a month-to-month tenancy by a written notice given to the other at least thirty days prior to the periodic rental date specified in the notice.

So the best-case scenario is that you can stay in the property for another 30 days before you have to move out.
(This assumes that your cousin is not willing to renegotiate the terms of your tenancy, e.g., you start paying rent every week or month.  They might be willing to do this, but if they just want you gone, they have no legal obligation to renegotiate.)

"It's not clear to me whether you would be considered a "tenant" under Iowa law." That is very wrong and how people get in trouble with illegal evictions. Look up tenant at will, §562.4 and get yourself a landlord-tenant attorney.

@user71659:  Are you saying that the OP is "in the possession of real estate" in the sense of that paragraph?  That might be the case;  I don't know enough to say, which is why I said it wasn't clear to me. If you're pretty sure that's the case, then I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Also, I agree with you that the cousin could easily get themselves into trouble by assuming that the OP does not have the rights of a tenant; but the cousin is not the one asking the question.

@user71659 How is he ‘very wrong’ for saying he was not sure about something?

@suchiuomizu "It's not clear to me that X" is generally interpreted as "I don't think X", but with a qualification that they're not certain. If it's obvious that they're wrong, then even the suggestion is "very wrong".

@Barmar  For the record, I just meant "I don't know whether X is true or not".  (I probably would have used "that" rather than "whether", as in your phrasing, if I had meant it in the way you suggest;  but that's a point of usage probably better debated in [English.SE], not here.)

germany
In Germany, you get rights when you pay rent. So if it’s the other way around and you let someone live in your home to help them out, it is strongly recommended to not accept some small rent payment so they don’t acquire any rights.
So in Germany you would have no rights. Because you are not a “non-paying renter”, you are not a renter at all.

The OP says that they paid their cousin some money "when they could";  does that qualify as a rent payment for the purposes of German law?

Also, note that the question was tagged "Iowa", which one of the United States.

@MichaelSeifert That is not a DV reason: Other jurisdiction answers are allowed and encouraged.

@Trish I agree!  That's why I did not downvote.  Must have been someone else.
